# SQL Server using pivot/transpose

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I need to transpose/pivot a question and looking for the best approach to do this:

original:

| ID | accountno | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | How old are you? | 15 |
| 2 | 111 | What is your favorite color? | blue |

final result:

| ID | accountno | How old are you? | What is your favorite color? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 15 | blue |

Here is my attempt:

```
--I only did the first question to see if it would work
select [ID],[accountno], [How old are you?]
from 
(select ID,accountno,question,answer
from table
PIVOT 
(max(answer)
For
question in ([How old are you?])
```

Comment: You can't transpose arbitrary values to column names. Also, you _probably_ don't need to pivot in SQL (because it's a _presentation layer concern_, not a _data concern_. Why do you want to pivot in SQL?

Comment: I don't understand what question is being asked - could you add some clarifying context? What was the result of your attempt, how did that differ from what you were expecting or wanting?

Comment: Out of curiosity what result would you expect 5 questions, or 50 questions?

Comment: It is less than 10 questions. It is in the format that is required to submit the report to an agency.

Comment: @mfm5105 Then use your reporting engine to transpose the table, not SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close.  Tale a peek at the following

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select accountno
              ,question
              ,answer
         From YourTable
       ) src 
 Pivot ( max(answer) for question in ( [How old are you?]
                                      ,[What is your favorite color?]
                                     ) ) pvt
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: so close! Now I am getting this error :Pivot columns must be comparable. The type of column "name" is "text", which is not comparable.

Comment: @mfm5105 Goodness TEXT has been depreciated for years.   convert to varchar or even nvarchar